# Self-Hosted Public Nameservers do not return FQDN

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

(Results from queries are only representative samples)

I am new to public DNS management. I have setup 2 nameservers in Azure. I have pointed my domains over to them and created forward lookup zones that point to my web server.

When I query one of them, I get the following result:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION
example.com 3600 IN A 64.52.100.100
example.com 3600 IN NS DNS1.
example.com 3600 IN SOA DNS1. HOSTMASTER.
```

I am wondering why my dig command is not returning the FQDN for my domains? When I query Google, I get the following result:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION
google.com 3600 IN A 172.217.10.174
google.com 3600 IN NS ns2.google.com.
google.com 3600 IN SOA ns2.google.com. dns-admin.google.com.
```

Why does google return FQDN, but my nameservers do not? Is this something that I need to correct? if so, How?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the trailing period or include the domain name.

Comment: Thank you for informing me how to resolve the issue. Is this something that we must do? Is this a requirement or best practice?

Comment: I have no idea what interface or files you are using, but a `.` terminates the DNS record as all records end in a period, there azure interface may assume you are entering a fqdn and append the period.

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2016 with DNS Service installed.

Comment: Oh, that's a bit foolish imho.

Comment: Show true queries and replies if you want to get answers. Also if you use a paid service like Azure did you ask their customer service?